# What kind of code would it take to visualize just 1 3d gaussian in Godot?

Tags: rendering, shader, glsl, c#, godot

I'm trying to create the simplest possible implementation of the gaussian visualization code from this paper in Godot, https://repo-sam.inria.fr/fungraph/3d-gaussian-splatting/ but I just don't even know where to start, if I knew how to visualize even just one 3D gaussian using C# mono code or GDScript code or Godot Shader code or GLSL code then I feel like I'd have a leg on implementing something for my classes, but I read the code in the github: https://github.com/graphdeco-inria/gaussian-splatting/tree/main and it's like 1000s of lines across 50 files all intermingled to do what it's doing. There's no getting started tutorial to implementing this code, so that's what I'm asking for, how do I draw a 3D gaussian with alpha?